# I am getting undefined for the shared data injected in a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

So I am trying to inject a shared data into a directive to be used by a validator to validate the email input by the user. My problem is I am getting 'undefined' for the value of my shared data from inside the directive. Here are the snippets:

registration.html

```
  div class="form-group md-form" [class.has-error]="email.touched && email.dirty && email?.errors?.emailExist">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" email="true" appCheckEmail [(ngModel)]="dealerRegistrationInput.email" #email="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
     <div class="help-block alert alert-danger " *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched) && email?.errors?.emailExist">
     <div [hidden]="!email.errors.email">
      A valid email is required.
     </div>
    <div [hidden]="email?.errors.emailExist">
      This email address already exist
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

registration.ts

```
.......
 constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route:  ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private sharedData: SharedDataService,
    private connectService: ConnectService,
    private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.connectService.getAllDealers().subscribe((dealers: Dealer[]) => {
      this.sharedData.dealers  = dealers;
      console.log('Dealers.....' + JSON.stringify(this.sharedData.dealers));
    });
  }
 ............
 .........
 .............
```

check-mail directive

```
    import {  Input, Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { Validator, FormControl, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
    import { SharedDataService } from './shared-data.service';


    /* ......Functions.........................*/

      function appCheckEmail(dealersEmails: string[]) {
console.log('Dealers..:   ' + JSON.stringify(dealersEmails)); //THIS IS UNDEFINED
           return (control: AbstractControl) => {
  console.log('Dealers email addresses2:   ' + JSON.stringify(dealersEmails));
  console.log('Control value: ' + control.value)
  ...

  ...
      if (dealersEmails.indexOf(control.value) >= 0) {
                   return null;
           } else {
              return{  emailnotExist: true  };
           }
        };
       }

     /* -------------------------End of Functions.............*/

    @Directive({
      selector: '[appCheckEmail][ngModel], [appCheckEmail][ngModel]',
      providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckEmailDirective),
        multi: true
      }]
    })

    export class CheckEmailDirective implements Validator {
      validator: Function;

      constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) {

      this.validator = appCheckEmail(sharedData.dealers); /* sharedData.dealers is undefined */
         }
         validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
            return this.validator(control);
          }

        }
```

somehow the shared data in the directive despite the injection is not pointing to the correct reference or the value is cleared. 
I also observed something very curious ...the checkMail directive is been executed once the html is rendered...before any data entered and apparently on every keystroke of the targeted input field....could this behaviour be causing the problem?
I would appreciate any help I can get.

--EDIT--
Having changed the appCheckEmail parameter to `appCheckEmail(sharedData:SharedDataService)`

and the indexOf search to:

```
 if (sharedData.dealers.indexOf(control.value) >= 0){....}
```

The search still fails to find a match. I have confirmed with console.log that the  sharedData.dealers array is in fact an array of strings and the control.value is a string with the values I am expecting. I have also tried simple for loop with:

if(sharedData.dealers[i] === control.value)
I even tried:
if(sharedData.dealers[i] === 'emailinarray@mail.com')

and both fails. I know I am a missing something fundamental here but I can't seem to find it. Could it be that sharedData.dealers[i] is still pointing to the wrong place even though I passed the reference in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `dealers` to the validate function, you should pass the reference to your service to the function. The problem with your solution is the fact that the `dealers` doesn't exist in the `constructor`. You are fetching the `dealers` in your `Component` asynchronously, so they can't exist during build time in your `Directive` constructor

```js
import {  Input, Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, FormControl, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedDataService } from './shared-data.service';


/* ......Functions.........................*/

function appCheckEmail(sharedData: SharedDataService) {

  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    console.log('Dealers email addresses2:   ' + JSON.stringify(sharedData.dealersEmails));
    console.log('Control value: ' + control.value)
    ...

    ...
    if (sharedData.dealersEmails.indexOf(control.value) >= 0) {
      return null;
     } else {
      return{  emailnotExist: true  };
    }
  };
}

/* -------------------------End of Functions.............*/

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCheckEmail][ngModel], [appCheckEmail][ngModel]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckEmailDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CheckEmailDirective implements Validator {
  validator: Function;

  constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) {
    this.validator = appCheckEmail(sharedData); /* sharedData.dealers is undefined */
  }
  
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.validator(control);
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the reference. I am now able to see the sharedData in the appCheckEmail function but no comparison I tried is working.....please see my edit to the question.

Comment: That's strange. The validate function is getting called everytime when the input changes, so you should get a match when the user types the complete email in the form. Are you sure your delaers is a string array? You can try to convert both sides to lowercase letters and try again. Or maybe there is a hidden so whitespace somewhere

Comment: @SplitterAlex.....yes it's an array of strings confirmed by console.logging each element and using typeOf function.....and I don't believe in ghost!!

Comment: @Splitteralex...Problem solved.....the sharedData.dealers[] values had extra " around them apparently from pushing the Json.Stringify value onto  to the Array.